# How can i track user's choice in chrome when native app install banner shows using adobe analytics

Tags: google-chrome, adobe-analytics, manifest.json

My mobile website when viewed on chrome, pops up the banner to ask the user if he/she wants to install the native app. Am able to use this by using the manifest.json. Since this pop up behavior is driven by chrome, am unsure how to track this using Adobe Analytics. I can use beforeinstallprompt to get a call back into my application before the app install banner is shown (chrome lets me to listen to this event), but how can I propagate this to adobe dtm for analytics purposes? I want to know how many people saw this banner, how many dismissed it etc..

Thanks
K

Comment: I think, currently only add to home screen buttton for progressive web app returns a promise userChoice, and not for native web install banner

Comment: I'm not able to track it neither. Did you find any workaround?